# Mongodb - Array containing element and not containing another one

Tags: mongodb, collections, element, contain

I'm trying to query one of my mongodb collection that looks like this:

```
> db.collection.find()
{name: "foo", things: [{stuff:"banana", value: 1}, {stuff:"apple", value: 2}, {stuff:"strawberry", value: 3}]}
{name: "bar", things: [{stuff:"banana", value: 4}, {stuff:"pear", value: 5}]}
...
```

My goal is to list all the object that have the `things` field containing an element with `stuff=banana` but no `stuff=apple`

I tried something like this:

```
db.transactions.find({
  "things": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "stuff": "banana", 
      $ne: {
        "stuff": "apple"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The below query will get the list of all documents that have the `things` field containing an element with `stuff=banana` but no `stuff=apple`:

```js
db.test.find({"$and":[{"things.stuff":"banana"}, {"things.stuff":{$ne:"apple"}}]})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$not` and `$and` operators:

```
db.collection.find({

   $and:[
    {"things": {$elemMatch: {  "stuff": "banana"  }}},
    {"things": {$not: {$elemMatch: { "stuff": "apple"}}}}
  ]

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use $in and $nin to include and exclude

```
db.transactions.find({
  "things.stuff": {
    $in: ["banana"], 
    $nin:["apple"]
  }
})
```